# How to send query with select tag through url

Tags: php, html, database

I want send the data I received from the select tag through the url as queries so I can use it and query the database.

I have tried but the values are not showing. I am getting something like: type=&action=

This is my code

```
<select name="types">
    <option value="2 bed room">2 bed room</option>
</select>

<select name="action">
    <option value="rent">rent</option>
</select>

$type = $_POST['types'];
$action = $_POST['action'];

$query = "type={$type}&action={$action}";
<a class="site-btn fs-submit" href="search.php?<?php echo $query; ?>"> Advanced search</a>
```

I expected :

```
type=2 bed room&action=rent
```

Comment: What is stopping you? You have both values you need to pass over

Comment: those values are not showing in the url.
am getting a blank value like: type=&action=, in the url

Comment: _am getting a blank value..._ Where is your form? There should be a form having POST as method

Comment: this is my form:
 <form class="filter-form" method="post" action="search.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: _this is my form_ And where is it? SHow the whole relevant part of your code! We don't POST forms via href.. please read over the html basics

Comment: <form class="filter-form" method="post" action="search.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text "class="d-block d-md-inline" placeholder="Enter State, City or Area"> <select name="types">
                        <option value="2 bed room">2 bed room</op
                    </select>
                    <select name="action">
                        <option value="rent">rent</option>
                    </select>

Comment: the post array is filled once the form is submitted : form is shown > user input > user submit (bouton) > form action url is called by browser > _post array  is filled > values are in php

Comment: i have used GET method but its showing thesame thing

Comment: Edit your question and put complete code you are using. In the comment above you are not closing form so it will not work. You have to put submit button and than fetch the data at search.php Don't use link. You can't submit form with link.

Comment: am not submitting the form, i just want to pass the querry and use it to querry the database in the search.php.
the forms are well closed

Comment: You can't do it in that way. You will need to change the logic of the thing you are trying to do.

Comment: Pls tell how i can achieve it easier. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Here, When you submit the form the whole form data will be passed to `search.php` and the form method is `POST` so you can access those data by simply calling `$_POST['attribute value of name']`.

HTML form:

```
<form class="filter-form" method="post" action="search.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="text "class="d-block d-md-inline" placeholder="Enter State, City or Area" name="city"> 
    <select name="types">
        <option value="2 bed room">2 bed room</option>
    </select> 
    <select name="action"> 
        <option value="rent">rent</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Advanced search">
</form>
```

create a PHP file (`search.php`):

```
<?php
//Do what you want here
if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];

    echo $city;
}

if (isset($_POST['types'])) {
    $type = $_POST['types'];

    echo $type;
}

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    echo $action;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the link with a button. Attach the query params in the link to the action of the form. Your code should look like below.

```php
<form action="search.php?<?php echo $query; ?>">
<select name="types">
<option value="2 bed room">2 bed room</option>
</select>

<select name="action">
    <option value="rent">rent</option>
</select>

<?php

$type = $_POST['types'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
$query = "type={$type}&action={$action}";

?>

<button class="site-btn fs-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you're using `$query` before declaring it.